# jquery syntax : where to put "toFixed"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to round the result of following jQuery but I don't know where to put `.toFixed()`

> ```
>     (function ($) {
>         $(document).ready(function() {
>             $('#custom_coverage').keyup(function() {
>                 $('#result').text($('.reads').text() / ($('.amplicons').text() * $('#custom_coverage').val()));
>             });    
>         });
>     }(jQuery));
> ```

Who can help?

Comment: which one is a floating number? give some input examples

Comment: be cautious of using arithmetic operations on string variables (i.e. `.val()`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 (function ($) {
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#custom_coverage').keyup(function () {
             var raw = $('.reads').text() / ($('.amplicons').text() * $('#custom_coverage').val());
             var fixed = raw.toFixed(2);
             $('#result').text(fixed);
         });
     });
 }(jQuery));
```