# Where to put .toFixed(2) in the script to limit to 2 decimel

Tags: javascript

I have the following script to calculate amount.
Now I would like to limit the amount to 2 decimel.
I know that I need to use .toFixed(2). 
But I don't know where I can put it in the script.
I hope someone can help me.

```
var base = 39.95;
   var numberField = document.getElementById('numberField');
   numberField.onkeyup = numberField.onpaste = function() {
      if(this.value.length == 0) {
         document.getElementById('mpdresult').innerHTML = '';
         return;
      }
      var number = parseFloat(this.value);
      if(isNaN(number)) return;
      document.getElementById('mpdresult').innerHTML = number * base;
   };
   numberField.onkeyup();
```

Comment: You should first try to understand what your code does

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery syntax : where to put "toFixed"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716101/jquery-syntax-where-to-put-tofixed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('mpdresult').innerHTML = (number * base).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: I was figuring it out but I thought it need to be after parseFloat. And you're right edi9999, I'm working on it.

Comment: Since there is a loss of precision, it should be done as late as possible